# How to set slide down and slide up gesture in app widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Guys. I am developing app widget which show weather and traffic data. When user drop widget on home screen than weather data display in widget and when i slide up traffic data will load and display and when slide down again show the weather data. I tried lot and searched lot but not find any use full solution. I am able to load single view on home screen but not able to find sliding up down gesture.

Please guys help me out.

Thank You lots in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is usually not possible to make gestures on RemoteViews, only if You use certain views inside. The Views that support gestures are:

- ViewFlipper
- ListView
- GridView
- StackView
- AdapterViewFlipper

This depends on the API version where You are developing. Please refer:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

If You want to do something with this Views, here is a good tutorial:

http://www.broculos.net/2011/12/android-101-how-to-create-stackview.html#.U4XNxnZnOko